# How to hide textarea if input is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, textarea, show-hide

How do I use jQuery to hide textarea if input text is empty?

My attempt:

```
jQuery(document).chnage(function($) {
    var value=$.trim($('input').val());

    if (value.length < 0) {
        $('textarea[name="your-message"]').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: `jQuery(document).chnage`: Use _change_ event on `input`.

Comment: If input is empty its value length is `0`. Is `0 < 0`?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`keypress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress) or html5 [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event instead of change event for the input element and toggle using [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method in jQuery.

```js
// bind input event handler
$('input').on('input', function() {
  // toggle visible state based on value
  $('textarea[name="your-message"]').toggle(this.value.trim() !== '');
});
```

```css
textarea {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<textarea name="your-message"></textarea>
```

---

Issues in your code:

1. Since you are providing `$` as the callback param it holds `event` object inside the callback(not jQuery).
2. Change event only fires when the element loses focus after its value was changed.
3. You are only hiding the element inside the callback, no code present for showing it again.
4. `chnage` should be `change`(I think its a typo).

Answer (score 0):

Your real problem is that you redefine `$` with *another* value:

```
jQuery(document).change(function($) {
   // remove this bad boy -------^
   // $ is jQuery.Event object here
});
```

The first parameter to event handler is going to be [jQuery.Event](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) object, not jQuery itself.

Remove `$` from parameter list and use `value.length == 0` it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this might help you

```js
$('#txtID').on('input', function() {
if(this.value.trim() !== ''){
$('#txtID').show();

}else{
$('#txtID').hide();

}
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="txtID"></textarea>
```